# Receive email through Gmail & php file

Tags: php, email

Afternoon all,
I am pulling my hair out over something that can only be a silly mistake but so silly i cant track it down.
I receive no contact forms in my email of which i use Gmail.
At present i am testing it on this page here http://www.theremotedoctor.co.uk/accbmw.html?scrollto=selection
And on this item for sale on the right Virgin Chip ID44
Form is then shown on screen,customer completes & submits form.
They are then taken to my thank-you page BUT i never receive email.

Here is my php code.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "*********gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "DR CONTACT FORM";

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br><br>";
        echo $error."<br><br>";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br><br>";
        die();

    }

    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['post_code']) ||
        !isset($_POST['delivery_destination']) ||
        !isset($_POST['paypal_email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['part_number']) ||
        !isset($_POST['image_address']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $first_name = strtoupper($_POST['first_name']); // required
    $last_name = strtoupper($_POST['last_name']); // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = strtoupper($_POST['telephone']); // not required
    $post_code = strtoupper($_POST['post_code']); //not required
    $delivery_destination = strtoupper($_POST['delivery_destination']); // required
    $paypal_email = $_POST['paypal_email']; //required
    $part_number = strtoupper($_POST['part_number']); //hidden
    $image_address = $_POST['image_address']; //hidden
    $comments = strtoupper($_POST['comments']); // required
    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br>';
  }
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$paypal_email)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Paypal Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br>';
  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br>';
  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br>';
  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br>';
  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }

   // $email_message = "FORM DETAILS BELOW.\n\n";
    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= '<html><body>';  
    $email_message .= '<table rules="all"  border="1"  cellpadding="10" style="width: 560px; margin: auto; border-collapse: collapse;">';
    $email_message .= '<tr><th colspan="2">FORM DETAILS</th</tr>';
    $email_message .= '<tr><td style="background-color: #eeeeee"><b>FIRST NAME:</b> </td><td><b>' . clean_string($first_name) . '</b></td></tr>';
    $email_message .= '<tr><td style="background-color: #eeeeee"><b>LAST NAME:</b> </td><td><b>' . clean_string($last_name) . '</b></td></tr>';
    $email_message .= '<tr><td style="background-color: #eeeeee"><b>EMAIL:</b></td><td><b>' . clean_string($email_from) . '</b></td></tr>';
    $email_message .= '<tr><td style="background-color: #eeeeee"><b>TELEPHONE:</b></td><td><b>' . clean_string($telephone) . '</b></td></tr>';
    $email_message .= '<tr><td style="background-color: #eeeeee"><b>POST CODE:</b></td><td><b>' . clean_string($post_code) . '</b></td></tr>';
    $email_message .= '<tr><td style="background-color: #eeeeee"><b>DELIVERY DESTINATION:</b></td><td><b>' . clean_string($delivery_destination) . '</b></td></tr>';
    $email_message .= '<tr><td style="background-color: #eeeeee"><b>PAYPAL EMAIL:</b></td><td><b>' . clean_string($paypal_email) . '<b></td></tr>';
    $email_message .= '<tr><td style="background-color: #eeeeee"><b>PART NUMBER:</b></td><td><b>' . clean_string($part_number) . '</b></td></tr>';
    $email_message .= '<tr><td style="background-color: #eeeeee"><b>IMAGE ADDRESS FOR:</b></td><td><b><a href="' . $image_address . '" >' . clean_string($part_number) . ' IMAGE</a></b></td></tr>';    
    $email_message .= '<tr><td style="background-color: #eeeeee"><b>COMMENTS:</b></td><td><b>' . clean_string($comments) . '</b></td></tr>';        
    $email_message .= '</table>';  
    $email_message .= '</body></html>'; 

   // create email headers
   $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\n".
   'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\n" .
   'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
   $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
   $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\n";//ISO-8859-1

   @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 

   header('Location: http://www.theremotedoctor.co.uk/thank_you_page.html'); 
?>


<?php
}
?>
```

Please can you advise if you see anything wrong.
Many Thanks.

Comment: Most likely your messages are filtered as SPAM. You'd have to check your http servers error log file.

Comment: Have you tested the mailer with a minimal test email? You are suppressing errors with @. How about checking for an error and letting us know.  I always use https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Answer (score 0):

Try using PHP [mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Your code will look like this:

replace this:

```
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

with this:

```
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

In gmail create a filter to filter all emails with the subject "DR CONTACT FORM" that will ensure that your email doesn't go to spam.

**How to create filters:**

In gmail go to settings > Filters and Blocked Addresses > Create new filter > 
leave all fields blank except for subject which you must add *DR CONTACT FORM* 
then click create new filter with this search (bottom left corner) and then click check box that says never send to spam > 
create filter and *you're done!*

Comment: abc is hard let alone this php as im doing this 3rd hand.
You say SPAM is that before i even see it in my email or its sent to me but then spammed ?

Comment: sent to you but gmail puts in spam box.. did you try the using mail() ?

Comment: I will be honest mate this is all new to me so unable to follow however easy this might be

Comment: I understand

I will edited my answer

Comment: Hi,
Ive changed the code in the php as advise,ive completed and sent the form.Give it a few minutes now to see if i receive anything.Thanks for your input.

Comment: Hi, Okay cool, you're welcome.

Comment: Hi,
Nothing at all received

Comment: could you open your error log please(in cpanel in the same directory there will be a file error_log) open and see whats the last error logged, also in the console is there any error ?

Comment: Ive had to look up cpanel etc as im new to this.
I found on my remote site cpanel but nothing about error log at all just caches,datastore,nvdata, etc.I am also getting message on here about extended discussions,can i email you ?

Comment: inside file manager where the actual files for your website is located.

Comment: That is where i got that info,Filezilla,cpanel on my remote site

Comment: yes inside filzilla where you see the list of all the file you uploaded do you see an error_log file ?

also check when you are submitting form keep your console open and see for any errors

Comment: In filezilla i see the cpanel folder,i have been through every folder within it but there is nothing like error file at all

Comment: Just saw now that $email_message is not defined, on the first one remove the .

Comment: Please advise line number or code that im looking for,then what i should do to it

Comment: this one:     $email_message .= '<html><body>';

Comment: ok but now do what with it

Comment: change to this: $email_message = '<html><body>';

also go and enable errors so you can see what error you get on the page: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/4285276